# How to get the destination IP when accepting a connection with a UdpSocket?

Tags: networking, rust, udp

I am using `UdpSocket` to create a server, binding to `0.0.0.0:serverport`. I can get the source IP when a datagram arrives by using [`recv_from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.recv_from).
However, I need to get my local server's IP (destination IP) which the remote client contacted. I can see it in Wireshark but cannot obtain it via the API.

Motivation: I have 2 IPs from same network, `eth` and `wlan`. When a client contacts me on my `wlan` IP, in Wireshark I see the response UDP packet will have the correct port (same as request), but the source IP is the IP of my `eth` interface, thus the client will not receive the answer. Listening on just my `wlan` IP does solve the issue, but I want to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: Does this work in `C`? If yes, then you may convert your socket into a [`raw_fd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.AsRawFd.html#tymethod.as_raw_fd) and use C functions to obtain. I don't see an obvisous way to achieve this in pure rust, except opening two different sockets on each interface.

Comment: No, there's no C API to do that either in such a setup. The "workaround" is to create one socket per interface, that way you know which socket the datagram arrived on. (Or to set up the networking such that packets that goes out on eth0 can communicate with the wireless network  - which it should when both eth0 and wlan are on the same subnet)

Comment: Thanks. @nos - the networking is set up correctly, the packet will arrive at the remote computer, however the client program will not read it because it contacted different IP.